# execute network executable file in cmd script?

Tags: windows, cmd

I wrote a myweb.exe and myweb.cmd.

myweb.cmd is

```
start myweb.exe  My Web Options 
start http://localhost:8080
```

If I put these files on a local folder, it works when user click the myweb.cmd.

But, it failed if I put these files on \\mysrv\myweb\ directory.

Windows will show myweb.exe not found. (It seems the myweb.exe is put on c:\windows)

Answer (score 1):

One of these two could help.

```
@echo off
start "" "c:\program files\name\myweb.exe"  My Web Options 
start http://localhost:8080
```

This may work on a LAN if you have permissions.

```
@echo off
start "" "\\server\share\myweb.exe"  My Web Options 
start http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: I want to let the myweb.cmd not static write "\\server\share" directory, could I get "current network path"?

Comment: If you place myweb.exe on the system PATH then it could work.

Comment: I'm wonder if there any %xxx%\myweb.exe could be written, we I can put the cmd file in server and read-only, and let users just press the network folder's icon.(Because I don't want to hard-code the server name and directory name), and don't want user to install.